# How can I replace the value in the csv file?

Tags: bash, csv

I have csv file in this format

```
movie|7m21s
```

i want replace 7ms21 on time in seconds 7*60+21=441

```
movie|411
```

How can i do this in linux bash?

Answer (score 2):

Use awk:

```
awk -F'|' '{ split($2,a,/[ms]/); print $1 FS a[1]*60+a[2] }' file
```

Set the field separator to a `|`. Split the second field into the array `a`. Print the first field, a "|", then use the values in the array to calculate the second field.

Answer (score 1):

With bash builtin commands:

```
while IFS="|" read -r c1 c2; do m=${c2%m*}; s=${c2#*m}; s=${s%s}; r=$[m*60+s]; echo "$c1|$r"; done < file
```

Output:

```
movie|441
```